# controller error container Sencha

Tags: extjs

I am developing an app with sencha cmd and time of implementing a dataview shows me error and will not let me finish or show me what I should like to show. 
I'm desperate for the error, is :

```
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#onFirstItemAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration
```

As much as I searched I have not found the solution, and not understand why I get this error, do not try to make a tab panel, simply a dataview with two fields json, one name and an image below

You help me please to see the error? Thanks

The code from my dataview:

```
            Ext.define('catalg.view.VistaRuta', {
                   extend: 'Ext.Container',

                    alias: 'widget.fit',
                    xtype:'rta',
                    autoScroll: true,
                config: {
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'dataview',
                            height: '100%',
                            styleHtmlContent: true,
                             width: '100%',
                             title: 'rta',
                            layout: {
                                type: 'fit'
                            },
                            inline: {
                                wrap: true
                            },
                            itemCls: 'dataview-item',
                            itemTpl: [
                                '<div class="arHeadline">',
                                '    {titulo}',
                                '</div>',
                                '<div class="arbyline">',
                                '    <img src="{foto}" />',
                                '</div>',

                            ],
                            store: 'rtaStore'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            docked: 'top',
                            title: 'look 10 rta',
                            autoScroll: true,

                        }
                    ]
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A `Container` may not contain any docked elements, only a `Panel` can contain docked elements:

   - `Ext.Component`: a simple html component (most visibly Ext object inherit from this)
   - `Ext.Container`: a component that can contain other components
   - `Ext.Panel`: a container that has a header and can contain docked components
   - most likely you will use a panel with some containers or other components in it
   - there is also a shortcut for setting docked components: `tbar` (=top bar) and `bbar` (=bottom bar)
2. why do you define an alias and an xtype? you should only use one of them (and the alias `fit` could easily create a name collision):

   - if you define a custom component you give it a name in a namespace `catalg.view.VistaRuta` which is all you need to create this component: `Ext.create('catalg.view.VistaRuta')`
   - cause this so long you can define aliases like `alias: 'widget.rta'` or `xtype:'rta'` so you can crate this component by using `xtype:'rta'`
   - I prefer using the alias cause there are other things like `proxy.`, `plugin.` or `feature.` you can create aliases for, `xtype` is only for components
   - always choose only one method `alias` *OR* `xtype` so there is no conflict

Comment: Thank you for contest, I have little time with sencha and so far I've always "needed a" xtype in views to main.js can interpret. What is right? 

I'll check and you commented. Thank you!!!

Comment: I just updated my answer to explain you a few things :)

Comment: Thank you, really! Now I understand everything better! I'll make practices to solve my problems. Thank you!

Comment: Jan S thank you very much for your help, served me well, and fix any errors using what you said! Thank very much :)